# Android Studio 3.6 Make Project / Build fails no reason given

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I upgraded to Android Studio 3.6 (only change), which I am regretting BIG time!

Now my Android project won't build and no reason is given

(1) Gradle sync started  and ends with no error

(2) Make Project or build to run on device/emulator reports::
   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleInternalDebug] 
   Gradle build failed in 1s 730ms
nothing else

```
Build failed at 4/2/20 20:43
:app:preBuild  UP-TO-DATE
:app:preInternalDebugBuild  UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileInternalDebugAidl     (has no entry sign)
:app:mergeInternalDebugShaders
:app:compileInternalDebugShaders
:app:compileInternalDebugRenderscript (has no entry sign, all the rest have check ma)
:app:generateInternalDebugAssets
:app:mergeInternalDebugAssets
:app:processInternalDebugGoogleServices
```

(3) tried removing .idea and .gradle  from project

(4) i have tried downgrading Gradle to 3.5.3  same issue

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Thanks,  I have already done that, and resync to project, clean project and rebuild project  no effects